# dynamically name variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i condense this into a loop and name the variables dynamically?
this works

```
var aMainNav = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'];
aMainNav[0] = $('.mainNav li:nth-child(1)');
aMainNav[1] = $('.mainNav li:nth-child(2)');
aMainNav[2] = $('.mainNav li:nth-child(3)');
```

this doesnt

```
var aMainNav = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'];
var i = 0;
while(i < aMainNav.length){
    var j = i++;
    eval(aMainNav[i] = $('.mainNav li:nth-child('+j+')'));
    i++;
}
```

and the button clicks

```
aMainNav[0].click(function(){
    myLocation=='abc'?top.location.href='https://mydomain.com?var=1':window.location.href='./';
    return false;
});
aMainNav[1].click(function(){
    myLocation=='abc'?top.location.href='https://mydomain.com?var=2':window.location.href='./';
    return false;
});
aMainNav[2].click(function(){
    myLocation=='abc'?top.location.href='https://mydomain.com?var=3':window.location.href='./';
    return false;
});
```

Comment: What is your goal with the `b1`, `b2`, etc.? In both of your examples, you're just overwriting them.

Comment: I think you can redesign your entire code - the `.click` lines are almost identical as well.

Comment: @pimvdb im learning, any examples will definitely come in handy : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to tell from the question, but I wonder if this is what you were looking for:

```
var aMainNav = {};
var n;
for (n = 1; n <= 3; ++n) {
    aMainNav['b' + n] = $('.mainNav li:nth-child(' n + ')');
}
```

The end result of the above will be an object referenced by `aMainNav` which has properties `b1`, `b2`, and `b3` which are the relevant `nth-child`s. E.g.

```
aMainNav.b2.css("color", green");
```

...would turn `.mainNav li:nth-child(2)` green.

Comment: yes,  i was looking for objects!  this worked at the end `var aMainNav = {};
var n, j;
for (n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
 j = n+1;
   aMainNav[n] = $('.mainNav li:nth-child('+ j + ')');
}
`

Comment: I'm curious why you're using a numeric index (`aMainNav[n]` when `n` is `0` to `2`). Where did your `b1`, `b2`, etc. go? But if you want to do that, `aMainNav` doesn't have to be a plain object (although there's no harm in it), it can be an array if you like. Either way.

Comment: i had 2 different ideas confused

Answer (score 2):

Try `var j = ++i;`, and remove the second `i++`. You don't even need the eval.

```
while(i < aMainNav.length){
    var j = ++i;
    aMainNav[i] = $('.mainNav li:nth-child('+j+')');
}
```

<strike>When</strike> <strike>if</strike> Never use eval, but if hypothetically you were to use eval (crosses self), remember that it takes as its argument a string of Javascript to evaluate, not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a `for` loop and also avoid using `eval`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < aMainNav.length; i++){
    aMainNav[i] = $('.mainNav li:nth-child('+ (i+1) +')');
}
```

and for the click handlers

```
for (var i = 0; i < aMainNav.length; i++){
    aMainNav[i] = '.mainNav li:nth-child('+ (i+1) +')';
}


$(aMainNav.join()).click(function(){
    myLocation = 'abc'?top.location.href='https://mydomain.com?var=' + $(this).index() + ' ':window.location.href='./';
    return false;
});
```

1. Modified the array to hold strings instead of jQuery object
2. change `myLocation ==` to `myLocation =`
3. User `aMainNav.join()` as that would select all `mainNav li` child elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. It simply appends to the list instead of directly stating an index point. If you need to specify an index point, that is what dictionaries are for, so you should be using that instead of an array.

```
var aMainNav = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'];
var i = 0;
while(i < aMainNav.length){
    var j = ++i;
    var item = $('.mainNav li:nth-child('+j+')'));
    aMainNav.push(item);
    i++;
}
```